# Plotting the RealExponent of difference of two solutions of a equation with respect to delay

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have obtained the following equations from Wolfram documentation.

```
sol = First[ 
   NDSolve[{x'[t] == (1/4) x[t - τ]/ (1 + x[t - τ]^10) - 
       x[t]/10, x[t /; t <= 0] == 1/2}, x, {t, 0, 5000}, 
    MaxSteps -> ∞]];

solrk = First[ 
   NDSolve[{x'[t] == (1/4) x[t - τ]/ (1 + x[t - τ]^10) - 
       x[t]/10, x[t /; t <= 0] == 1/2}, x, {t, 0, 5000}, 
    MaxSteps -> ∞, 
    Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 3}]];
ListPlot[Table[{t, RealExponent[(x[t] /. sol) - (x[t] /. solrk)]}, {t, 17, 5000, 17}]]
```

The same equation has been solved twice using two different methods and `RealExponent[d]` has been plotted with respect to time. Here `d` is the difference between `x[t]` computed by the different methods.

My question is How to plot `RealExponent[d]`  with respect to `τ`, where `τ` can be varied from 14 to 40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically what I think you're looking for.  The `RealExponent` of the difference is stored in `red` as a list of triples `{τ, t, d}`.

```
Clear[x, t, τ, sol, solrk]

sol[τ_] := Block[{t, x},  (* so  Table[]  doesn't overwrite  t  *)
   sol[τ] =               (* remember the solution so that it won't be recomputed *)
    First[NDSolve[{x'[t] == (1/4) x[t - τ]/(1 + x[t - τ]^10) - x[t]/10, 
       x[t /; t <= 0] == 1/2}, x, {t, 0, 5000}, 
      MaxSteps -> ∞]]
   ];

solrk[τ_] := Block[{t, x},
   solrk[τ] = 
    First[NDSolve[{x'[t] == (1/4) x[t - τ]/(1 + x[t - τ]^10) - x[t]/10, 
       x[t /; t <= 0] == 1/2}, x, {t, 0, 5000}, 
      MaxSteps -> ∞, Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 3}]]
   ];

red = Table[{τ, t, RealExponent[(x[t] /. sol[τ]) - (x[t] /. solrk[τ])]},
   {τ, 14, 40, 4}, {t, 17, 5000, 17}];

ListPointPlot3D[red, Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]
[image]

The right plot is with a `Δτ` in `Table[]` of `2`.

Comment: Thank you for this response. In the 2nd plot did you take more steps? Can I ask for a 2D diagram only RealExponent and τ.

Comment: @Udichi Change the `4` to a `2` in the `Table` for `red`, to get the plot on the right. -- What do you mean 2D? You could plot `Table[{τ, RealExponent[d]},...]`, but I think the result will be a bunch of dots basically filling in a vertical line segment for for each value of `τ`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I have used the command                                                                   ListPlot[Table[{\[Tau], 
   RealExponent[(x[t] /. sol[\[Tau]]) - (x[t] /. 
       solrk[\[Tau]])]}, {\[Tau], 14, 40, 4}]], but not getting any result. What mistake is there

Comment: @Udichi I get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu55D.png, which is what I expected.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Thank you very much

Comment: @Udichi You're welcome.